# Using the_excerpt() some posts are truncated and some are not

Tags: posts, excerpt

I have a template that pulls three posts query_posts() loop. Two of the posts and are truncated to 10 words like I have it set in a filter. The third decided to ignore the filter and is spitting out 33 words. I can't see a difference between the posts. Does anybody know why this would happen?

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  $img = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Featured Thumbnail', true);
                    ?>
  <div style="width:237px; float:left; margin-right:20px;" <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <div class="entry">
    <img style="margin-bottom:10px;" src="<?php echo $img; ?>"/><br />
    <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h3>', '</h3>'); ?></a></div>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that post have an excerpt manually entered? the filter only works on excerpts when they're pulled from the post content.

Comment: I've been trying to find the place to add excerpts for posts and I don't see it.

Comment: If the excerpt field isn't visible when editing a post, click the "Screen Options" tab in the upper right corner and check the Excerpt box.

Comment: Had to fix my screen options drop down because of a bad plugin (Post Template). Now I see the excerpt.